# Как ожидать следущее сообщение без FSM на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

скажите: ЧЕМ ТЕБЕ НЕ НРАВИТСЯ FSM?
а на нём нельзя работать на группе с несколькоми пользователями
тоисть чел пишет в группу /start и пишет текст, все работает.
НО ЕСЛИ один чел пишет /start и ДРУГОЙ чел пишет текст то сообщение ВООБЩЕ не обрабатывается

```
class Form(StatesGroup):
    a = State()    

async def a(msg):
    await Form.a.set()
    await msg.answer('Напишите текст')

async def b(msg, state):
    await state.finish()
    await msg.answer('Текст получен')

dp.register_message_handler(a, commands=['start'])
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

можно сделать так:

```
async def a(msg):
    dp.register_message_handler(b)
    await msg.answer('Напишите текст')

async def b(msg):
    await msg.answer('Текст получен')

dp.register_message_handler(a, commands=['start'])
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

но я не нашёл способ ОТМЕНИТЬ регистрацию обработчика и поэтому текст будет обрабатываться БЕСКОНЕЧНО
на telebot есть next_step_handler НО ЧТО ДЕЛАТЬ В АИОГРАМЕ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @СергейШ с же написал БЕЗ FSM большим шрифтом как ты мог это не увидеть???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как начёт такого варианта?

```
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Напишите текст')
    # храним состояние пользователя в переменной
    user_state[message.from_user.id] = 'waiting_for_text'

async def handle_text(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    # проверяем, ждем ли мы от пользователя текст
    if user_state.get(user_id) == 'waiting_for_text':
        await message.answer('Текст получен')
        # меняем состояние пользователя
        user_state[user_id] = 'text_received'
    else:
        pass

dp.register_message_handler(start, commands=['start'])
dp.register_message_handler(handle_text, func=lambda message: user_state.get(message.from_user.id) == 'waiting_for_text')
executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: спасибо, я решил проблему аналогично как у вас
я вместо переменной указал состояние в базу данных
и в функции проверяю этот состояние

Comment: @CreeperHack тогда отметьте ответ как правильный, буду благодарен)